# Re-coding category-template.php to go to custom URL

Tags: categories, tags, codex

Thanks for the support everyone – love these forums!

Here is the issue:
– category and tag pages being automatically created aren’t fully customizable compared to normal pages.
– solution was redirecting category/tag pages to built-out pages with full content
– example: https://www.checkhookfighting.com/category/brazilian-jiu-jitsu/ redirects to https://www.checkhookfighting.com/techniques/brazilian-jiu-jitsu/

Question: is there a way to hardcode tags to pages in wordpress template?
– some initial research in WP taxonomies shows it may be possible?

Thanks everyone! Again <3 stackexchange forums!

– James

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirects (which sounds quite hacky, unless I've misunderstood the question completely), you can create a `tag.php` template (or a `tag-slug.php` or `tag-id.php` to be even more granular, if you need) and customize that one with native WP functions such as `single_tag_title()`.

Comment: agh exactly what im looking to do! (and yes the redirects were totally hacky hahaha...)

for the brazilian jiu jitsu example would i edit the tag.php template and customize it with the following code?

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
single_tag_title(brazilian-jiu-jitsu) https://www.checkhookfighting.com/techniques/brazilian-jiu-jitsu/

or use a .php file or? sorry.. still brushing up on this

Comment: Still not 100% sure I understand the situation: is your goal to redirect a tag archive page to a static page - or to customize a tag archive page so that it displays the things you want?

Comment: sorry that made no sense was exhausted writing it lol...

The goal is to customize a tag archive page so that it displays the things wanted. 

Originally was wondering if you could edit WP codex to say "if tag = boxing, go to "/boxing-page" instead of it's default tag created page.

But the other way around works (customizing the wordpress tags/category pages if possible).

Comment: Good, so the tag.php customization is the way to go :) it's still unclear to me, though, if there are any questions left for this specific thread?

Comment: Thanks Andrii!

Any docs on how to proceed? 

Is it okay on forum rules to offer payment for help in this? Would pay if we were able to successfully assign a tag to a URL of our choice and see steps taken to do so.

Comment: Stack Exchange rules do not allow paid replies, to the best of my knowledge, but if you describe your desired outcome in as much detail as possible, I (and others) will try to provide a solution :)